# Show alert instead of toast

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

as you can see from my code below I have got an if and else statement, where if it is if it will show a toast. Now what I want is that instead of the toast being displayed I want an alert to be displayed containing some text and an Ok button.

```
            @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (index==5){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "More coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        position2 = (index++);
                    }
                    String textValue = values[position2];
                    tv.setText(textValue);
                    Random RAND = new Random();
                    int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
                    String nextValue = colors[position];
                    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
                    n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00,00,00,00));
                    return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00,00,00,00));
                    return true;
                    default:
                    return false;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Give it a try and ask again if you get stuck. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 1):

if you are inside the Activity class

```
showDialog(this);
```

if you are outside the Activity Class.

```
 private Context mContext;

 public void setContext(Context context) {
    mContext = context;

 }

showDialog(mContext);
```

Function.

```
public void showDialog(Context context) {  

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context) 
.setMessage("More coming soon!")
.setTitle("Your title here..")
.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
         dialog.dismiss();
    }

 });

 builder.show();
}
```

just replace it with the Toast.
Context is the usualy the Activity so if your inside the Activity send "this"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, any explanation for this: http://gyazo.com/48858afd43cd82dc1a181f5818ca1b46 ? Context is red underlined?

Comment: sure : the Touch got Events when the Event is ACTION_DOWN which mean the user placed the finger on the Screen. again Context is usual the Activity but depends where you call the function. if it help you please mark it as Answer.

Comment: So instead of Context I put Activity?

Comment: you can use getApplicationContext i just said if you call it from inside the Activity Class use "this"

Comment: Im sorry for my misunderstanding, have only been programming for like two days now. You mean like this: (this) ? It is still red underlined

Comment: I am sorry I just don't get it. I would highly appreciate it if you could edit my code :) *** I added the private Context context code and now it isn't red anymore** But the app now crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59466/discussion-between-cristianowilson-and-itzik-samara).